# How to stop jQuery Script from executing more than once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using PHP condition to execute J's query if a condition is met...
Something like

**PHP/jQuery**

```
if($rowCount>0){
//run the code below
?>
<script>
alert("There's an autoSaved data from last visit");
</script>

<?php
} ?>
```

It works as I expected! I've this temp_table in my DB where I store temp files, incase the user left a draft or probably got interrupted somehow without posting then I can retrieve this data when next he tries to post with 2 options, either the user deletes the previous or start from previous draft...
if rowCount is > 0 then there's a draft.. I don't know if I'm using the right method but the code works well but it iterates the script alert() each time the user (on same page) tries to continue from previous upload (I used Ajax to process image upload) but if the user clicks the upload button... The alert shows again... How can I make this  execute just once?

Comment: Well, if you keep making requests to this PHP script, it will trigger that alert every time, as long as a draft exists. Maybe you could add another column to the table which marks that the user started re-using the draft and use it to skip the alert? Or perhaps you could remove the draft from the table as soon as the user continues the input? You'll know what best fits your system.

Comment: I think there's a sense to your view! I could create a column "verified" to the temp_table and use something like $verified = " "; "SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE verified='".$verified ;           at first the 'verified" colmn is empty, so this will select all! if rowCount >0 show alert,   then once the user confirms the alert I could update the column to "Verified" in this case the Boolean is false! 